# Mlogit multinomial probit model: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, mlogit

I am trying to use the `mlogit` package to estimate a multinomial probit model, but I get the following error.

```
Error in if (is.null(initial.value) || lnl <= initial.value) break : 
      missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

These are the statements that I used

```
dat <- read.table("C:\\Users\\Data.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t", row.names=NULL)
brand <- mlogit.data(dat, shape="long", choice = "choice", varying = 3:7, sep = " ", alt.levels=1:7, id.var = "id")
brand.mprobit <- mlogit(choice ~ last + price + ad + shelf | pers_1 + pers_2 + spend, probit = TRUE)
summary(brand.mprobit)
```

My data looks as follows:

```
  obs   choice  person  option  last    price   ad  shelf   pers_1  pers_2  spend   ago
1   0   101 1   0   0.38    1   1   1   9   20  4
1   0   101 2   0   0.44    0   0   1   9   20  4
1   0   101 3   0   0.33    0   0   1   9   20  4
1   0   101 4   0   0.64    0   0   1   9   20  4
1   1   101 5   0   0.55    0   0   1   9   20  4
1   0   101 6   1   0.18    0   0   1   9   20  4
2   1   102 1   0   0.99    0   1   1   9   23  5
2   0   102 2   0   0.66    0   0   1   9   23  5
2   0   102 3   0   0.45    1   1   1   9   23  5
2   0   102 4   0   0.56    0   0   1   9   23  5
2   0   102 5   0   0.78    0   0   1   9   23  5
2   0   102 6   1   0.18    0   0   1   9   21  5
```

The last 4 columns are only individual specific, while the others are alternative specific. Could anyone please help?